# Ploltly express scatterplot does not allow for sorting categorical labels

Tags: python, express, sorting, plotly, scatter

It seems that setting the categoryorder of the x-axes makes px.scatter figures crash when using marginal plots

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px # plotly 4.9.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['c', 'a', 'b'], 'y':[1,2,1]})
fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', marginal_y='box')
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending') # Line x
fig.show(renderer='browser')
# Only works, if line x is removed, or when parameter marginal_y='box' is removed
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update layout

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px # plotly 4.9.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['c', 'a', 'b'], 'y':[1,2,1]})
fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', marginal_y='box')
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type='category',categoryorder='category ascending'))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why your approach works and mine does not?